# Load VBscript in html file

Tags: html, vbscript

I have a problem with loading my VBscript in html. I tried to test a simple sample, but it doesn't work:
My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="login_VBS.vbs"> </script> 
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

login_VBS.vbs:

```
msgbox "this is a message"
```

I can not make it easier, but when I check the view source from IE, the vbs doesn't exist in my source. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **valid** HTML - like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript" src="test00.vbs"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

and one (or both) scripting language specification; of course the .vbs must exist (in the parent folder of the .html file, if you don't use a full/absolute path).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have gave correct filename with correct location, this should work

```
<script type="text/vbscript" src="VBScript_file_URL"></script>
```

[**Check this**](http://www.herongyang.com/VBScript/IE-Browser-Include-VBScript-Codes-as-External-Files.html) and also [**this**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1), also make sure whether the file exists or not.